# Update Contact fields while Community User Creation

Tags: contact, customer-portal, customer-community, user-registration

Use this line of code
Site.createPortalUser(user, acc.Id, password);

We can create a user and create a new record of contact under that Account. However, the new contact has no other data added, e.g. the address. On the visualforce page we want the user to add their address and make the newly created contact has the address data. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did the update in code by using DML execution.